# how to update a cryptosystem for users?

Tags: passwords, cryptography

i guess that algorithms used to crypt password becomes weaker year after year due to the new technologies (CPU more powerful, GPU...),

So; does this mean that a user registred in 2006 is less protected than who has registred in a 2012?

Then; how to update the password of that user of 2006? (for example Yahoo, if am registred since 2006, then my password takes less time to crack than the password i'll put in 2012, so how Yahoo will do to update my password to the new powerful system?)

In other words: how to migrate from a system to another (from MD5 to Bcrypt for example for the existing MD5-hashed passwords)

Comment: StackOverflow is the wrong place to ask. The issue could be that a 2006 password is weaker than a recent one, just because it is shorter. You could change all your passwords to >12 characters length with some non-letter characters inside.

Comment: what i mean, for example if i want to migrate to BCrypt from MD5, for example, how do i convert  my MD5 passwords!

Comment: You don't convert it. You ask your users to change passwords (or you change your own password), using a new implementation. If it was easily convertible, that would mean that it was very insecure in first place.

Comment: so as i guess,if Yahoo want to secure their users passwords with the new PBKDF2/BCrypt/SCrypt, they'll ask their 2006's users to change their password?

Comment: Why not run BCrypt on the MD5 hashes? So instead of storing MD5(salt | password), you'd store BCrypt(MD5(salt | password)). Updating passwords would be a one-time operation. EDIT: @AbdelouahabPp -- are these passwords used to generate encryption keys, or are they used for logging in?

Comment: and then how do i verify the password on login? i must verify twice? if BCrypt OR BCrypt(MD5(salt | password))!

Comment: No --- you'd store all FUTURE passwords as BCrypt(MD5(salt | password) as well. Then just check against this value.

Comment: Related questions: [Is this password migration strategy secure?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2945/is-this-password-migration-strategy-secure), [Migrate old MD5 passwords to BCrypt passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771198/migrate-old-md5-passwords-to-bcrypt-passwords)

Comment: @Seth so there will be a lost time (double checking) for the new users due the oldest ones :(
NB: thses password is for logging in.

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: The main problem with using MD5 to hash logins is that MD5 is too fast, fast enough that dictionary attacks are feasible. (To my knowledge, there is still no efficient way to find MD5 preimages, even though MD5 is broken in terms of collision resistance). BCrypt is intentionally much slower. The "lost time" is a feature, not a bug. :)

Comment: yes, letting the client and the hacker wait with BCrypt :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two actual problems:

- CPU power increases, so brute force cracking increases
- Older algorithms get less secure

The latter one is fixed by changing the way you normally hash and store passwords in your database. You can already do this every time a user logs in when their password is stored in the old format.

The first one requires an actual change of the password and you should 'force' users to update their password every so often and check (or at least indicate) password strength when they enter a new one.

Another way to counter the increased CPU power is to limit the number of password tries after a number of failed ones and thus prevent brute forcing of the password.

In general though I think proper management of password storage is lacking in most websites and systems.

Comment: thank you :)
i think it will be the lonly solution: forcing users to update their password after 1 year for example, this will cut Moore Law by two, and can clean forsaken accounts.
BTW: SCrypt scales well with time, you only specify max time, so more you add RAM+CPU, more the password gets complicated!

Answer (score 1):

If your hashing scheme involves just repeatedly hashing the current value (1000s of times), then you can always later increase the iteration count (just not decrease it).

You can use bcrypt as your iteration function so you get the benefits of both schemes.

Like this:

```
var hash = bcrypt(pw, salt);
for N iterations:
 hash = bcrypt(hash, salt)
```

You can always "append" new iterations in the future.

Comment: thank you, 
 the problem is about older users, in SCrypt you can specify the max time, so it will scale well with the Moore Law, but how to update elder users :'(