# Convert wordpress password to BCrypt-based

Tags: mysql, wordpress, spring-security, encode

I have an old project which is using Wordpress, currently we create a new project and need to migrate the user's data into the new database (also Mysql).

The new database is using Bcrypt for encoding password for users. The old encode type in wordpress is like:

```
$P$BdsGKKQnnH6mi9hznpibst1jl/6G4z1
```

I think it might be MD5-based or not. I looked this link: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use`

I want to find a way to convert this type of password to Bcrypt-based. Maybe mysql script could help me convert? Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I checked the good solution below to migrate Md5 to Bcrypt.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771198/migrate-old-md5-passwords-to-bcrypt-passwords
 But if $P$BdsGKKQnnH6mi9hznpibst1jl/6G4z1 is not md5, how do I authenticate the user with this wordpress encode mechanism?

Comment: I found this project to convert phpass to bcrypt.
https://github.com/Wolf480pl/PHPass

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if you can login to the admin panel or not. Chances are that you cant, but if you can somehow reset the password field with a known bCrypt hash for the admin. Then you can use this plugin to change the encryption from md5 to bcrypt for all your passwords.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-bcrypt/