# migrating b-crypt hashed passwords from Ruby on Rails to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, bcrypt

I have an application with user table and hashed passwords created by Devise in a RubyonRails website.

I want to migrate those users to Wordpress.

According to PHP documentation you can use the BCRYPT algorithm for passwords, and this is the same encryption method (afaik) that is used by Devise.

The hashed passwords I have are all 60 characters long, and they all begin with the prefix $2y$

However, when I try to follow the code example

```
<?php
echo "Welcome to PHPSandbox";
$hash = '$2y${MyHASHEDPASSWORDHERE}';
password_verify('{MYPASSWORDHERE}', $hash)
```

It outputs `false`

Yet when I follow the example on [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)it outputs true.

Devise must have added some extra complexity to the Hash Password and so now when I run password_verify using PHP 8 it is not able to verify that the hash and the password match.

How can I verify the hashed passwords coming from Devise on Ruby on Rails application in PHP?

Comment: I would check to see if you have `:pepper` defined, that might be messing you up. Otherwise, unless it is a custom implementation of bcrypt it should [just work](https://3v4l.org/h3HBO). Can you post a demo hash along with the corresponding password? Also, you'll want to remember that WordPress uses MD5 by default, so you'll either want to use the [migration pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10775785/231316), or switch [WordPress over to bcrypt](https://github.com/roots/wp-password-bcrypt)

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm guessing there is a pepper in place that is the reason that password_verify is not working on the hashed passwords I have.  

I was planning to either use wp-password-bcrypt plugin or write my own to override WP's MD5 defaults.   My client is not keen on asking users to use the reset password option, and wants this in a hurry so migration pattern might take a while

I'll include a demo hash and password in my question above

Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Migration of password can be integrated into the application while still on the old system.

You would need to have the old password hashing mechanism in place, and the new algorithm plus a second column in your database to store the password with the new hashing method.

When the user authenticates, eg. the first password check validates the password, you can hash it with the second method into the second column (you'd only do this, if the second column is empty yet)

At some point, you remove the old password hash & database column. Anybody who hasn't authenticated until then must go through the "password forgotten" process.